# How to "Mark as Shipped" in PayPal using PayPal .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I have PayPal payments set up using PayPal .NET SDK. Everything works fine, but the customer wants to automatically update a payment transaction as shipped when an order in our application is completed. When looking at a PayPal administrative interface, there is a link "Mark as Shipped," but I am not able to find any matching functionality in [the API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/).
With which API I can set this status on transactions?